# How can I securely provide a user with a new password in a PHP/MySQL web application?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I have a simple question. What is the best way to do a password recovery for a user?

I want the user to be able to click a link like "forget your password?" When clicked, the user will receive an email with a new password.

I think sending the hash is a bad option, then I must generate a random password, convert to a hash + random salt, replace it in the database and send the new random password by email. Is this the best way, or is there another?  Simpler is better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safest way is to email the person a link to a page that allows them to create a new password.  Passwords should only ever be stored as salted hashes.  Subverting this process would require that a person's email be compromised -- in which case they've probably got worse problems than a compromised password to your webapp.

---

### Files and tables:

I imagine that your database contains a table called "users", with a column called "userid" which serves as its primary key.

1. Create a new table in your tabase called `password_reset` with three columns: `userid`, which is a foreign key pointing to the table `users`; `code`, which will contain a unique, random number; and `timestamp`, which will contain the date that a request is made.
2. Create a page for password resets, like `password_reset_request.php`.  Ask for a username or email.
3. Create a page for setting a new password, like `set_new_password.php`.

### Logic:

1. If the username or email supplied to `password_reset_request.php` is valid, insert a row in the `password_reset` table corresponding to the request.  Imagine that user *Fel* has placed a password reset request.  *Fel*'s internal `userid` might be *564979*.  The row in `password_reset` would be something along these lines:  `564979, 54c4a2767c2f485185ab72cdcf03ab59, 2011-01-01 12:00:00`.
2. Send an email to the user's email address containing an url looking like this:  `http://your.url/set_new_password.php?userid=564979&code=54c4a2767c2f485185ab72cdcf03ab59`.
3. When `set_new_password.php` gets a hit, it should check for the presence of the `userid` and `code` properties in the URL.  Not there?  **Abort.**
4. Sanitize the `userid` and `code` properties if they're there.  This is important.
5. Run an SQL command like this: `SELECT * FROM password_reset pr WHERE pr.userid = $userid AND pr.code = $code AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURTIME(), pr.timestamp) < 1`.
6. If you receive no results, **Abort.**
7. If you receive a result, allow the user to enter a new password.
8. After validating the password as you normally would upon registration, use an SQL `UPDATE` statement to change the user's password.
9. Use SQL to delete any requests for the user from the `password_reset` table:  `DELETE * FROM password_reset WHERE userid = $userid`.

You're done!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. Your suggestion is, the user post your email or username, and it is send an email with a link where the user can create a new password. How i create the link? what is the process? it is a random link? thanks

Comment: it seems complicated to me. Do you know any web tutorial or something like that? thanks syrion

Comment: This is relatively simple; I have never seen a web tutorial about it.  I will edit my answer again to make it a little more clear.

Comment: There you go!  I've greatly expanded the detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

1. User requests password reset
2. User enters either username or password
3. An e-mail is sent to the user with a link with a unique hash that is placed in a database table (e.g. pwrecovery) - this link would be like: http://domain.com/pwrecover.php?key=KEYHERE
4. The user clicks that link, if the hash exists in the table then they get sent another e-mail with their new password.

That way, users wont find their password being changed by random users when they get a correct e-mail.

Comment: man i think that a simple email with a new random word (if the user want, he can change the pass when do the first login), it is ok.

Comment: But if I get a users e-mail address I can reset their password every day and all they can do is change their e-mail address to stop me from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should email a link to a page with a security question (and a unique code to prevent people from getting other people's security questions).

After answering the question, allow the user to create a new password.